# Limit scope of `newcommand` (without using `renewcommand`)?

Tags: latex

I'm combining a few latex documents and would like to limit the scope of my macros. I would like something like the following to work:

```
{
\input{macros1.tex}
\input{body1.tex}
}
{
\input{macros2.tex}
\input{body2.tex}
}
```

Where `body1.tex` uses macros defined via `newcommand` in `macros1.tex`, and `macros2` and `body2` are similar. However, `macros2.tex` might *redefine* commands found in `macros1.tex`. I thought that the braces might limit the scope of the macros, but it seems like that is not the case (I get "command already defined errors). Is there a way to solve this without replacing everything in `macros2` with `renewcommand`?

Comment: This sounds a bit like an x-y-question. Can you describe a bit more what problem you are trying to solve? Are you trying to combine different documents into one document?

Comment: Correct, I'm just trying to combine a bunch of existing documents (or parts of existing documents) that may have clashing macros.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subdocs ? I did test it myself (to lazy to create a test file :P ), but the description sounds as if it might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Macros defined inside groups get local scope. However other things, such as length names or custom counters, still become global at least by default as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104194/31283). While it is possible via packages, author of those files would have to prepare code for this case.

If you uncomment lines (re)defining counters and names in this code below, you get error "<something> already exists"

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{fileA.tex}
\newcommand\xxx{A}
\newlength\lenx
\setlength\lenx{15pt}
\newcounter{cx}
\setcounter{cx}{3}
\xxx, \the\lenx, \thecx
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{fileB.tex}
\newcommand\xxx{B}
% \newlength\lenx   % !!! Error
\setlength\lenx{30pt}
% \newcounter{cx}   % !!! Error
\setcounter{cx}{6}
\xxx, \the\lenx, \thecx
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{fileC.tex}
\newcommand\xxx{C}
% \newlength\lenx   % !!! Error
\setlength\lenx{45pt}
% \newcounter{cx}   5 !!! Error
\setcounter{cx}{9}
\xxx, \the\lenx, \thecx
\end{filecontents*}
%%%
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%%% Group A
\begingroup
\input{fileA.tex}
\endgroup

%%% Group B
\begingroup
\input{fileB.tex}
\endgroup

%%% Group C
\begingroup
\input{fileC.tex}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```